# jquery checkbox like gmail

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for a component like this one (from gmail)
Can I do something like that with jquery ?

Regards 
[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/faq - the last paragraph under "How do I ask questions here?"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is "probably" going on. That check box is likely surrounded by a div or span with a nested inside as well. When the surrounding container is clicked, the drop down is triggered to show.

Comment: also, the drop down is *not* triggered when you click on the checkbox, at least not in my browser. **Edit:** Instead, it is toggled.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't look at gmail, I just assumed it may do that. Thanks!